# Обрезание блоков на Ipad

Tags: ipad, html, ios, css

При просмотре кода на Ipad'e блоки обрезаны с правой стороны, хотя ширина 100%. В чем проблема?
http://rghost.ru/55715542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**<meta name="viewport" content="width=1260">** - это должно помочь

**width** - установите свою ширину

По умолчанию ширина окна просмотра на iPhone устанавливается равной 980px. Но ваш дизайн может не соответствовать данному диапазону. Значение может быть для шаблона слишком большим или маленьким.

[посмотрите здесь](http://wpandyou.ru/tutorials/html-css-jquery/viewport-meta-teg-dlya-ne-adaptivnogo-dizajna-sajta-non-responsive-design/)

Comment: Ещё в подобных случаях стоит смотреть margin-ы и padding-и. В различных обстоятельствах и в различных браузера их влияние на ширину блока меняется. Например в ширину могут входить и маргины и паддинги, или не входить ни те ни другие.

Comment: а причем здесь margin and padding?

Comment: Здесь непричём. Но в некоторых ситуациях подобные спецэффекты могу возникать и из-за них. Так-что стоит иметь в виду.